# Unity c# help, doodle jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game similar to doodle jump.

I have programmed my camera to go up after the player but not down, so when the player goes down off camera view he loses.

I also want the obstacles that are spawned to be destroyed when they are out of the camera view. I have attached a script to them but it is not working because I am attaching the script to the main object and if it is destroyed then there can't be any more spawning things, so I need to attach the script some how just to the clones, not to the main game object or you may help me write a good script.

```
     public GameObject player;
        public Camera camera;
        public GameObject obstacleclone;
        public GameObject platform;
        void Start () {

        }

        void Update () {
            if(camera.transform.position.y > obstacleclone.transform.position.y + 10f 
             || camera.transform.position.y > platform.transform.position.y + 20f)
            {
                platform.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
        {
            StartCoroutine ("go");
        }
        IEnumerator go()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Renderer.OnBecameInvisible
It will be called wehn object is no longer visible

```
 public void OnBecameInvisible() 
{
     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
```

But your game is endless runner type so use object pooling than creating and destroying objects.It can be simple or complex depending on your needs.
Also attach camera to your main player so it will follow your player.

Comment: Thanks, all of you i have repaired that problem, happy that theree is support on stackoverflow, if i will have questions then i iwll ask, thnk you very much!